# Different behaviour of same statement while executing on JShell

Tags: java, java-9, jshell, java-10

I was working on a problem to store reference of two classes within each other

For Example:

```
class A {
B b;
A(B b){
this.b = b;}
}

class B {
A a;
B(A a){
this.a = a;}
}

public static void main(String...s){
A a = new A(new B(null));
a.b.a = a;
}
```

Now if instead of above initialisation, if I use below statement:

```
A a = new A(new B(a));
```

I got below error which is quite obvious:

```
Main.java:19: error: variable a might not have been initialised
        A a = new A(new B(a));
```

But if I try the same on JShell, it works just fine (Just to be extra sure that `variable a` has never been initialized, I checked for `variable a` just before executing the statement which confirms that it was not initialized before:

[image]

May be I am missing something here, but can some one please help me to understand why there are two different behaviours of the same statement being executed in JAVA.

A simple way to understand this problem is that below statement is allowed in `Jshell` but not in normal program:

```
var somevar = somevar;
```

Comment: No, thats not the case, I checked for a just before this and got |  Error:
|  cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   variable a
|  a
|  ^

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Updated the screenshot as well

Comment: If it really is doing what you say, it seems to me like a bug in jshell.  If I were you, I'd report it to Oracle.

Comment: Thanks @DawoodibnKareem

Comment: it is a circular dependency. is it?

Comment: Yes right, but as shared it is working fine in both the case, but with different statements @nidhin

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Not a bug. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49585559/5221149).

Comment: A simpler example could've been `Integer x = x`, what do you expect the compiler to do? Jshell pretty much [works as explained by Andreas.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49585559/1746118)

Comment: @nullpointer I have already shared what compiler usually do in such scenarios. Definitely the explanation by Andreas makes perfect sense

Comment: This one accepted as a bug now. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49888971/1262248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I totally agree with @Andreas answer above that this is expected with the way initialisation is currently working in JShell, I also have the same view as @Dawood that JShell should work to normal compiler as close as possible, otherwise it can sometime be uncertain and hence unsafe to use.

For this particular scenario, I raised an issue with Oracle and it has now been accepted as an official bug. You can track more about this bug here:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8200567

Hope that this will be resolved soon in the upcoming releases of JShell.

Answer (score 10):

The statement `A a = new A(new B(a));` is **not** the declaration of a local variable.

But first, the issue you're describing can be simplified to:

```
jshell> int a = a;
a ==> 0
```

Now, how did that work?

Well, as [**Snippets**](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222#Snippets) of JEP 222 says it:

> In JShell, a "variable" is a storage location and has an associated type. A variable is created explicitly with a *FieldDeclaration* snippet:
>
> ```
> int a = 42;
> ```
>
> or implicitly by an expression (see below). **Variables have a small amount of *field semantics/syntax*** (for example, the `volatile` modifier is allowed). However, variables have no user-visible class enclosing them and **will be generally viewed and used like *local variables***.

So, they behave a little like fields and a little like local variables.

Like a field, but unlike a local variable, a declaration without initializer will assign a default value, e.g.

```
jshell> int b;
b ==> 0
```

But, back to `int a = a;`. Section [**State**](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222#State) of JEP 222 says:

> The JShell state is held in an instance of JShell. A snippet is evaluated in a JShell with the `eval(...)` method, producing an error, declaring code, or executing a statement or expression. **In the case of a variable with an initializer, *both declaration and execution occur***.

So, the declaration of the variable, and the execution of the initializer, are two separate actions.

This means that when the initializer is executed, the variable has already been declared, and has already been assigned the default value.

In effect, `int a = a;` is evaluated as:

```
jshell> int a;
a ==> 0

jshell> a = a;
a ==> 0
```

This is how the jshell REPL is designed to work. It is not a bug.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas.  It answers the question.  The specification that you quoted was actually the documentation that I was looking for before I posted my comment.  However, I still disagree with the categorisation of this as "not a bug".  Oracle have described the purpose of jshell as _"...learning the Java programming language and prototyping Java code..."_.  The fact there are cases in which jshell behaves differently from Java means that jshell fails to be fit for purpose.  That's a design bug, regardless of whether or not Oracle describe the buggy behaviour in a specification.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem By it's very *nature*, a REPL violates the Java syntax (e.g. statements outside methods), so although the *intent* is to allow prototyping, it cannot be 100% true to Java. If that's what you expect/want, don't use a REPL. This is one example of a *documented* difference. The difference is *by design*. Since 100% Java is an impossibility in a REPL, you can't claim that designed differences, which making REPL actually workable, is a "design bug".

Comment: One could argue JShell is just following the [Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1): Although assignments are right-associative (i.e. `a=b=c` means `a=(b=c)`), the order of statement processing in case of variable assignment describes: _[...]three steps are required:

    First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable.[...]_